# How to define a function?

Tags: python-3.x, function

When I run the script it says that the function (main) is not defined,
but if I put the 'main' function to the top, it will just run that without the validation

I've tried different names and positions,

```
def validation():
    pin=int(input("please enter the pin \n::"))
    if pin == 56910:
        main()
    else:
        print("please enter a valid pin or leave")
validation();


def main():
    option=int(input("Hello welcome to my password managing program,    
    \n please select from one of the following options below \n 1-Checking existing e-mail and password, \n 2-Creating new password for a website")) 

    if option == "1":
        print("hello")
    if option =="2":
        print("option 2")
main();
```

"please enter the pin 
::56910
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MartinSomogyi/Documents/password_management.py", line 8, in 
    validation();
  File "/Users/MartinSomogyi/Documents/password_management.py", line 5, in validation
    main()
NameError: name 'main' is not defined"

> > > 

Comment: You call validation before defining main.

Comment: If you want to define the function `main` without calling it yet, *don't put `main()` immediately after it!*

Comment: thanks jasonharper that solved it I've just relaised my stupid mistake

Answer (score 1):

Your script currently:

1. defines validation()
2. calls validation()
3. defines main()
4. calls main()

but `validation()` in step 2 calls `main()` which is not defined until step 3, hence the error. In python all your script in the top level (i.e. anything that's not a function or class definition, an import or a simple assignment) should go at the **end** of your file for this reason, preferably in a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, like so:

```
def validation():
    ...

def main():
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    validation()
    main()
```